# What is the meaning of the size attribute on the /topics/topic/stats element

Tags: activemq-classic

When I retrieve a list of topics from the ActiveMQ admin web interface via a call like

```
http://localhost:8161/admin/xml/topics.jsp
```

I get an xml file which looks like this:

```xml
<topics>
    <topic name="some name">
        <stats size="some number"
               consumerCount="some number"
               enqueueCount="some number"
               dequeueCount="some number"/>
    </topic>
    <!-- more topic entries like above -->
</topics>
```

What is the meaning of the `size` attribute on the `stats` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of messages currently in the destination. ActiveMQ shares a lot of internal code between queues and topics, and this is one field that doesn't generally apply to topics and can safely be ignored.

Comment: If `size` applies to queues only, then in that context, what is the difference between `size` and `enqueueCount` - `dequeueCount`?

Comment: enqueueCount and dequeueCount are ephemeral. Those 'counting' metrics are only since the broker started. Size is absolute. A broker could be shutdown with 63 messages still in the queue. Upon restart size = 63, enqueue = 0, dequeue = 0